# renaming dataframe column in a list

Tags: r

I have a list with two dataframes (each with two columns) and I want to rename a specific column in this list.

```
sample_df1<-data.frame(coltest11=1:6,coltest12=5:10)
sample_df2<-data.frame(coltest21=5:10,coltest22=1:6)

sample_ls<-list("a"=sample_df1, "b"=sample_df2)

colnames(sample_ls[["a"]][2])<-"test"

names(sample_ls[["a"]][2])
```

but the result is

```
[1] "coltest12"
```

I spent more than an hour looking at other topics but can't figure out what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current problem is that you are accessing the second entry in the list, then taking its names and trying to change it.  Instead, if you want to rename the *second* column in the `a` data frame, then just access the second entry in `names`, and rename it:

```
names(sample_ls$a)[2] <- "test"     # the [2] belongs on the outside, not inside
sample_ls$a

  coltest11 test
1         1    5
2         2    6
3         3    7    
4         4    8
5         5    9
6         6   10
```

**Data:**

```
sample_df1 <- data.frame(coltest11=1:6, coltest12=5:10)
sample_df2 <- data.frame(coltest21=5:10, coltest22=1:6)
sample_ls <- list(a=sample_df1, b=sample_df2)
```

Comment: thanks a lot! there are just so many ways of doing the same thing and as a beginner, I'm really struggling with even to get the fundamentals right...

Comment: Don't use loops in R, as a general rule.  Here, most likely you would just want to use `apply` with some vector of names/replacements.  Maybe ask a follow up question if you have an actual bigger problem than this.

Comment: great, thanks. I will generate some reproducible code and ask the follow-up question.